# django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Could not find the GDAL library via Homebrew

Tags: python, postgis, postgresql, geodjango, django

Django 4.1.5 on M1 Ventura 13.3.1 (22E261) failing to detect GDAL installation even when enumerated [per the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/gis/install/geolibs/#gdal-library-path). Is this a version error or a pointer error? I don't really understand what could cause this. According to the django docs, this newer version of GDAL [is not compatible](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/gis/install/geolibs/#installing-geospatial-libraries) with Django. Would that cause it to fail to be detected?

**Error Message**

> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Could not find the GDAL
> library (tried "gdal", "GDAL", "gdal3.4.0", "gdal3.3.0", "gdal3.2.0",
> "gdal3.1.0", "gdal3.0.0", "gdal2.4.0", "gdal2.3.0", "gdal2.2.0"). Is
> GDAL installed? If it is, try setting GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH in your
> settings.

**Environment Settings:**

interpreter python 3.11 in a pipenv:

`/Users/<username>/Documents/GitHub/optiagbe/venv/bin/python`

gdal 3.6.4 installed via homebrew at:

`/Users/<username>/homebrew/Cellar/gdal/3.6.4/lib/libgdal.32.3.6.4.dylib`

gdal virtual pointer located at

`/Users/<username>/homebrew/lib/libgdal.dylib` appears to properly point to the above installation

**Django Project Configuration:**

settings.py

`GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH = '/Users/<username>/homebrew/lib/libgdal.dylib'`

`GEOS_LIBRARY_PATH = '/Users/<username>/homebrew/Cellar/geos/3.11.1/lib/libgeos_c.dylib`

Answer (score 0):

This appeared to be the result of some forced homebrew update that occured when I installed another package earlier today. Steps to resolve:

1. Uninstall postgis: `brew uninstall postgis`
2. Uninstall GDAL: `brew uninstall --force gdal`
3. Unisntall poppler: `brew uninstall poppler`
4. Cleanup: `brew cleanup`

**Reinstallation:**

1. Install new postgis `brew install postgis` (This should install the dependent GDAL lib and poppler).

**Relist paths in Djagngo settings.py**

`GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH = '/Users/<username>/homebrew/Cellar/gdal/3.6.4/lib/libgdal.dylib' GEOS_LIBRARY_PATH = '/Users/<username>/homebrew/Cellar/geos/3.11.2/lib/libgeos_c.dylib'`

**Cause**

My build was previously stable with this config:

`GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH = '/Users/<username>/homebrew/Cellar/gdal/HEAD-3493a0f/lib/libgdal.32.3.7.0.dylib'`

`GEOS_LIBRARY_PATH = '/Users/<username>/homebrew/Cellar/geos/3.11.1/lib/libgeos_c.dylib'`

Looks like the auto-update from `3.11.1` to `3.11.2` that homebrew ran caused the file path in django settings to become invalidated. Typically you can get the version-agnostic path of a brew lib at `/Users/<username>/homebrew/lib/libabsl_flags.dylib` such that when the package is updated, it doesn't break django. For some reason the GDAL installation did not place the shortcut in this folder so it will break again when it updates. [Similar to this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75048449/21717888)